# Debug mode failed in JBoss 5.1 with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jboss

I have a problem when I start jboss 5.1AS in debug mode on eclipse. After many executions in debug mode that works fine, if I start or restart the server on debug mode it stops working and never starts again in debug mode on eclipse.

The only solution known is delete the .metadata folder in the workspace, but is not good for me, because I have to build again the workbench and all the configurations for my projects.